# Responsive iFrame resizing

Tags: html, css, iframe, responsive

I'm trying to add a chatbox to my webpage, which is otherwise mobile-friendly and responsive to browser size. I've added the chatbox to an iFrame, though it does not want to resize along with the rest of the page and is staying static. I was hoping there was a way to resize the chat box so it can dynamically change size and aspect ratio along with the page. I am planning on allowing this to be used by mobile users, but cannot figure out how to get this to work correctly.

Any advice is appreciated.

Here is a simplified version of my html and css.

**index.html**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="maincontent-area">
        <iframe src="chat.html" width="400" height="600" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

**chat.html**

```
<HTML>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9,10,11" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script id="cid0020000123830884525" data-cfasync="false" async src="http://st.chatango.com/js/gz/emb.js" style="width: 400;height: 600;">{"handle":"frequency84","arch":"js","styles":{"a":"33CCFF","b":100,"c":"000000","d":"000000","k":"33CCFF","l":"33CCFF","m":"33CCFF","p":"10","q":"33CCFF","r":100,"fwtickm":1}}</script>
</head>
</body>
</HTML>
```

**style.css**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.mainmenu-area {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fbfbfb;
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed",sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Figured it out, thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using media queries.

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px){ /* change to your mobile size */
    .mainmenu-area{
        width:/* new width */;
    }
}
```

You might even have to change how your targeting the iframe

```
.mainmenu-area iframe{
    /* code here */
}
```

instead of just

```
.mainmenu-area{
   /* code here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make the iframe width to 100%

```
 <div class="maincontent-area">
    <iframe src="chat.html"
    width="100%" height="600" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe>
  </div>
```

And on chat.html

```
<script id="cid0020000123830884525" data-cfasync="false" async src="http://st.chatango.com/js/gz/emb.js" style="width: 100%;height: 600;">{"handle":"frequency84","arch":"js","styles":{"a":"33CCFF","b":100,"c":"000000","d":"000000","k":"33CCFF","l":"33CCFF","m":"33CCFF","p":"10","q":"33CCFF","r":100,"fwtickm":1}}</script>
```

Working example below

[image]

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3r3rdr3m/)

Comment: Didn't do anything to the chatbox upon resizing.

Comment: You also needs to make width 100% in chat.html
        <script id="cid0020000123830884525" data-cfasync="false" async src="http://st.chatango.com/js/gz/emb.js" style="width: 100%;height: 600;

Comment: That seemed to fix the resizing issue, it will change aspect ratios and size now. How do I go about making it the 400x600 pixels though? It is currently taking up the entire width of the browser.

Comment: You can give max-width:400px in css, not sure about your layout and desired requirement. The main issue was fixed width which is gone now, so you can accept my answer now.

Comment: @RobertKulevich you should accept this as an answer since the answer fixed your issue, just informing you if you dont know.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your iframe

```
<div class="maincontent-area">
  <iframe src="chat.html" width="100%" height="600" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't do anything to the chatbox upon resizing.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px){ /* change to your mobile size */
    .mainmenu-area{
        width="100%";
    }
    iframe{
        width="100%";
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please, add some explanation

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this and it works for me. Hope it will help you.

```
<div class="map">
  <iframe src="" width="2560" height="500" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

And css:

```
.map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
.map iframe {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```